# Please Help in evalutaing this Definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want a little help with this question
$$ \int_{-\pi /4}^{n\pi -\pi /4} \left | sinx + cosx \right |dx $$

I tried to solve it by using the fact that since the following function is periodic with given period $\pi $ then we can say the integral is similar to the following - 
$n\int_{0}^{\pi} \left | sinx + cosx \right |dx $ then evaluated considering proper sign of the modulus function, but the answer is wrong. Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first try “normalizing” the interval over you do the integral:
with the substitution $x=t-\pi/4$, the lower limit becomes $0$ and the upper limit becomes $n\pi$; moreover $dx=dt$, so the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^{n\pi}\left|\cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|\,dt
$$
The function in the absolute value is
$$
\cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos t+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin t
+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin t-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos t
=\sqrt{2}\,\sin t
$$
Thus you remain with
$$
\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{n\pi}|\sin t|\,dt=n\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin t|\,dt=
2n\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin t\,dt
$$
the first equality because of periodicity $\pi$, the second one by positivity.

Note: this is much similar to Jeong Jinmyeong's hint, but doesn't require “guessing” other than applying the hint given by the authors of the exercise with the choice of limits.

Comment: @Lucas Why? $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$

Comment: egreg at the second row is $\sqrt{2}\color{red}{\sin t}$

Comment: @Lucas Oh! Thanks! The more you look into something, the less you realize there's a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

What you have done seems legit. But try to solve your problem by using the fact

$$
\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt 2 \sin\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\Big).
$$

By using this equation and by applying very natural integration by substitution, you will see very friendly integration.

This may help you concentrate, so make fewer mistakes. Once you got right answer, then check what mistake you've made: that's rewarding.